# pandas : efficiently multiplay row based on condition

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to multiply a row in `DataFrame` based on condition column .

For example, when value in condition column is 2, I'd like to substitute the row with two identical rows and set condition in each new row to 1.

Example DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'k': ['K0', 'K1', 'K1', 'K2'],
              'condition': [1, 1, 3, 2],
              's': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})


    condition   k  s
            1  K0  a
            1  K1  b
            3  K1  c
            2  K2  d
```

Desired result:

```
  condition   k  s
          1  K0  a
          1  K1  b
          1  K1  c
          1  K1  c
          1  K1  c  
          1  K2  d
          1  K2  d
```

Could this operation be done `inplace` efficiently, without creation a temporary `df` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster is use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
df = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values,df.condition)].reset_index(drop=True)
df['condition'] = 1
print df
   condition   k  s
0          1  K0  a
1          1  K1  b
2          1  K1  c
3          1  K1  c
4          1  K1  c
5          1  K2  d
6          1  K2  d
```

Another solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and last set values in column `condition` to `1`, but it is slower:

```
df = df.groupby('condition', as_index=False, sort=False)
        .apply(lambda x: pd.concat([x]*x.condition.values[0], ignore_index=True))
        .reset_index(drop=True)
df['condition'] = 1
print df
   condition   k  s
0          1  K0  a
1          1  K1  b
2          1  K1  c
3          1  K1  c
4          1  K1  c
5          1  K2  d
6          1  K2  d
```

**Timings**:

```
In [917]: %timeit df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values,df.condition)].reset_index(drop=True)
The slowest run took 4.55 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop

In [918]: %timeit df.groupby('condition', as_index=False, sort=False).apply(lambda x: pd.concat([x]*x.condition.values[0], ignore_index=True)).reset_index(drop=True)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.78 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you  @jezrael , I like your solution . I agree with you according to second variant , `groupby` looks slower